# code for NLP formula in latex

Tags: equations

[image]

how to write the following conditional equation by latex ,
I tried the following code but it not work

```
\begin{align}
T_{P_i} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{,T $\leq$ 1} \\
1+ \beta T & \text{,T$>$ 1} \end{cases}
in which T_{P_i} = \begin{cases} T_{now}-T_{last} & \text{,T_{last} $\neq$ NULL} \\
T_{now}-T_{update} & \text{,T_{last} = NULL}  \end{cases}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors that I see in your code.
Mainly, the use of subscripts inside `\text{}`. And also some things that might look better written in a different way.
This code produces something similar to your image.

```
\begin{equation*}
T_{i} = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{T $\leq$ 1}\\
1+ \beta T, & \text{T$>$ 1} \end{cases},
\text{ in which } T = 
\begin{cases}
T_{now}-T_{last}, & T_{last} \neq NULL \\
T_{now}-T_{update}, & T_{last} = NULL
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

If you need it inside the align environment, you can change of course, the `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` to `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`.

If you want to know a bit more why your code does or doesn't work, or about my code, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The following code produces the result you're after. I find it best not to try to make the various components line up in your tex editor as they would on the page because adjusting the zoom ruins it anyway.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
T(i) = \begin{cases} 1, T \geq 1\\1 + \beta T, T > 1 
\end{cases}\emph{, in which } T = \begin{cases}T_{now}- 
T_{last}, T_{last} \neq NULL\\T_{now}-T_{update}, T_{last} 
\neq NULL\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I more prefer the following result:

[image]

which is produced by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
T_{i} = \begin{cases}
1       ,   & T \leq 1\\
1+ \beta T, & T > 1 
        \end{cases},
\text{ in which } 
T = \begin{cases}
T_{\mathrm{now}}-T_{\mathrm{last}},   & T_{\mathrm{last}} \neq \mathrm{NULL} \\
T_{\mathrm{now}}-T_{\mathrm{update}}, & T_{\mathrm{last}} = \mathrm{NULL}
    \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```